# json response value fill to spinner

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I have json value as a response 
json value

### {student_name:xyz,projects:[science,maths],class:10}

So I wanted to ask, how do i get projects values and add these values to spinner.
Any Help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance,

Comment: first of all JSON is invalid and search on google for your requirement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Hi i wanted to fetch multiple values in one json paramter,